# Best books for Hören

Tags: learning, book, listening-comprehension

As you know **Hören** is a critical skill for improving the other skills (Schreiben, Sprechen and Lesen).

I am looking for a set of books that would teach me this skill and give me good exercises?

I am almost novice in German language, and I have already finished **Studio D A1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a project (Book2) where you can hear or download 100 exercises (common situations for novices i think) even in Persian-German:

> http://www.goethe-verlag.com/book2/FA/FADE/FADE002.HTM

The online exercises are limited (demo only), but you can download the complete mp3 files for free there (native speaker - man and woman):

> http://www.50languages.com/book2/FA/FADE/FADE-all.zip

Hope this helps. I am not involved in this project and don't want to advertise.

Answer (score 1):

It is for children, but I think that fairy tales are a good audio to improve your listening. Nearly everyone in Germany knows the fairy tales of Gebrüder Grimm. And I think they are easy to understand. Even if you do not understand every word it is easy to catch the message. 
Examples:
Hänsel und Gretel, Hans im Glück, Rapunzel, ...

Here is a link: http://www.loyalbooks.com/book/maerchen-by-grimm-1

Answer (score 1):

There is a news site in "leichter Sprache" called [nachrichtenleicht.de](http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/) (simple language) which might be good for a novice, since they use a limited vocabulary. They also provide audio that is spoken very slowly.

The public radio [Deutschlandradio](http://www.deutschlandradio.de/) provides its broadcasts as transcripts and as audio, but they will be challenging for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn the pronunciation of a language is watching TV.

Comment: Hello and welcome to German language Stack Exchange. Thanks for already taking the tour; if any questions remain, visit the [help]. I disagree with your answer, because I feel that listining to the radio is a lot better. There are so many TV shows that feature incorrect or otherwise bad German that just doesn’t happen on radios.

Comment: And when you consider the fact that OP is in Iran, your suggestion *might* be a bit difficult.